# Non-ASCII characters scrambled when writing response in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

If I put this Startup in an ASP.NET Core application the text will be scrambled (Ã…Ã„Ã–). Same thing happens if I do it in a middleware. Passing `Encoding.UTF8` to `WriteAsync` doesn't help.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(async context => { await context.Response.WriteAsync("ÅÄÖ"); });
    }
}
```

What's wrong and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to provide proper `Content-Type` header. Without it, browser is left guessing what content response represents, and in which encoding. And of course there is nothing wrong if that guess will be incorrect, like in your case.

```
app.Run(async context => {
    // text in UTF-8
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("ÅÄÖ");
});
```